# Testing Yii2 emails with mailtrap

Tags: php, yii2, mailtrap

I want to test out my emails sent from a Yii2 Application with mailtrap.
I have copied the exact configuration from mailtrap into my web config file.

My email configuration is as shown:

```
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
                'username' => '00xxxxxxcbe',
                'password' => '35xxxxxxx9d6',
                'port' => '2525',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
            'enableSwiftMailerLogging' => true,
        ],
```

I use the following code to send out a test email:

```
     public function actionIndex()
     {
            try{
                Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setFrom('name@email.com')
                    ->setTo('name@email.com')
                    ->setSubject('Message subject')
                    ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
                    ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
                    ->send();
    
                return $this->render('index');
            }
            catch(Exception $ex){
                $message = $ex->getMessage();
                throw new ServerErrorHttpException($message, '500');
            }
     }
```

If I set the useFileTransport option in the config to TRUE, I can see the email files that have been created. However if I set this option to FALSE, and try to use mailtrap, I get the below exception:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
```

I am using WAMP stack on windows.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: You should hide that username and password